# Reloading python module in all threads

Tags: python, django

I wrote some content management system on Django. User can create pages with various urls. For page routing, I'm using the default django url router mechanics:

```
pages = CMSHelpers().get_available_pages()

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', include('app.home.site.urls', namespace='homepage')),
    url(r'^search/', include('app.search.site.urls', namespace='search')),
    url(r'^ajax/', include('app.ajax.site.urls', namespace='ajax')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

for page in pages:
    if page.module.slug:
        try:
            urlpatterns += patterns(
                '',
                url(
                    '^%s/' % page.url.strip('/'),
                    include(
                        'app.%s.site.urls' % page.module.slug,
                        namespace=page.module.slug + '-' + page.module_params
                    ),
                    kwargs={'page_data': page}
                )
            )
            logging.debug("Imported url %s for module %s" % (page.url.strip('/'), page.module.slug))
        except ImportError:
            logging.debug("Cannot import urls.py for module %s" % page.module.slug)
            continue
    else:
        continue

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
)
```

**The problem:**

When django app is starting, python caches all urlpatterns. And when user changes url of some page via CMS, I'm reloading urlpatterns **but only for current uwsgi process/thread**:

```
    urlconf = settings.SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS["www"]
    clear_url_caches()
    reload(sys.modules[urlconf])
    reloaded = import_module(urlconf)
    if hasattr(reloaded, 'urlpatterns'):
        reloaded_urls = getattr(reloaded, 'urlpatterns')
        set_urlconf(tuple(reloaded_urls))
```

So user gets the random 404 error when he tries to access this page on site.

So, how I can reload module **for all uwsgi processes/threads**?

Comment: @SiHa, what you mean? Ugly formatting or that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that web apps like this are typically using "shared nothing" architecture, checking an external data store of some kind on each request is actually reasonable. Said external data store could have an update timestamp that each worker thread/process compares to their own last-updated timestamp and decides to reload the module if it is newer.

But, a nicer way to do this is to include a catchall url pattern for pages like `r'^(?P<url>.*)/$'` and route this to a single handler that looks up what the specific page's handler should be and invokes it.

Answer (score 0):

Save the user created patterns to the database.

Write some middleware that populates the url patterns to search on every page request.

Then you can have as many threads as you want. I suspect the overhead will be negligible.

Comment: Thank you, but it is the first thing that I've done :) Django reads urlpatterns only when django app starts. One time. And I don't want to disable the module caching - it is nice in performance case, but I want just reload modules when I need. So, I dont want the middleware that overrides urlpatterns every request - it will be slow in big apps.

Comment: reload(yourmodule)

Things will likely get ugly though. I think you need to reinstantiate instances of objects within the module you reload. 

You could use memcache to share info across threads but you would have to have 1 uwsgi process which is not ideal.

See the heading Sharing of global data
https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

You need to find some sort of shared storage for your url patterns

Comment: I know that it's ugly but i don't want to lose the default django routing mechanism (i like it) and want to give to users the ability to create pages with varoious urls. reload(modulename) will reload module only in current thread :( Shared storage is ugly too and app will more platform-depentent. The most simple approach - touch the wsgi file via subprocess.call() to reload uwsgi server but it's the ugliest thing too :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue.  I didn't want to hit the database on every missed URL.  I only wanted to reload the URLs when there was a change.

Since we are using uwsgi to run all of the django processes, I'd force a reload from the shell by sending the HUP signal to the uwsgi process.

In a django process, I just want to send a HUP signal to the parent process, which is the uwsgi process.  So I added these 2 lines to do that:

```
    import os, signal

    os.kill( os.getppid(), signal.SIGHUP )
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Killing UWSGI is really bad idea :) I aksed this question about 3 years ago and now I can say, that django is NOT designed to use dynamic URLs. Use static URLs and keep your apps in Django way.

Comment: This doesn't actually kill the process, but rather sends the HUP signal, which tells it to reload the config. The process stays the same. = )  

This process has worked really well for us.  We load the urls form the database only once, and our dynamic URLS work great.